# Where is $GLOBALS['cfg'] in phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

I found in phpinfo.php file under phpmyadmin, there is config setting with this:

```
if ($GLOBALS['cfg']['ShowPhpInfo']) {
    phpinfo();
}
```

I want to know where I can setup the $GLOBALS['cfg']['ShowPhpInfo'] config? Of course, I can hard code this array value, but I want to know the "standard" way for doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's set in `config.inc.php`, see for instance https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_ShowPhpInfo.

You can add a line like `$cfg['ShowPhpInfo'] = true;` to enable this feature.

Note that this feature had been temporarily removed between versions 4.6.4 and 4.6.6 due to concerns about leaking too much server information. You can see https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/12495 for some more discussion.