# PHPinfo page in PhpMyAdmin

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

i remember some old versions of PhpMyAdmin had option for inspect phpinfo(); page.
I need to see it on my new web hosting from PhpMyAdmin but i can find that option. 
Since i dont have File Manager or FTP access, please, give me only solution from phpmyadmin.

Comment: https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/12495

Comment: @ArtemIlchenko At the bottom it says it has been added again

Comment: @Jerodev I see it now, but how to find this option ... I have searched whole phpmyadmin.

Comment: https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/blob/master/phpinfo.php
So you need access to phpmyadmin config `$GLOBALS['cfg']['ShowPhpInfo']`

Comment: You need access to the filesystem in some form to change `config.inc.php` (the phpMyAdmin configuration file) and add `$cfg['ShowPhpInfo'] = true;`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/39887068/1035977 and the official phpMyAdmin documentation at https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_ShowPhpInfo

Answer (score -3):

Well if you cannot find it. You can check by creating it.

1. Open notepad then type `<? phpinfo(); ?>`
2. Save it as *.php* and put it *htdocs/www folder*

Comment: OP stated that he has no access to the files on the server

Comment: *Since i don't have File Manager or FTP access* ... so, that's not gonna help.